# How to parse command-line arguments from a separate function

Tags: c, parsing, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I am attemping to parse a command-line argument from one function `process_command_line` which I will then use in a `main` function. The second command-line argument enables the name of a file input to be submitted, which will later be used to read/write files. For the time being, I will just print out the argument within the `main` function to ensure that it is functioning correctly. I have had no issues parsing integers using this separate function method, but cannot get a correct output when trying to parse an `input` file name.

**EDIT**: I think my issue lies in the second function where I have a line saying `argv[1] = input_file;`

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int process_command_line(int argc, char *argv[]);   //declaration for command-line function

char str2[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("%s", str2);
    getchar();
    return 0; 
}

//This function reads in the arguments 
int process_command_line(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Missing program arguments.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //first argument is always the executable name (argv[0])

    //second argument reads in the input file name 
    strcpy(str2, argv[1]); //I think this is where the problem lies

}
```

Comment: You realize that you need to pass the arguments to the second function and call it, right?

Comment: Where you have `argv[1] = input_file;` did you intend `strcpy(input_file, argv[1]);`? If so you need to take steps to ensure that `input_file[]` does not overflow.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I'm not sure I understand what you mean- could you elaborate please?

Comment: Where is your call to `process_command_line()`?

Comment: You need to call that function in `main`, otherwise when do you think it's executed? Add `process_command_line(argc,argv);` before the `printf` (and a `\n` after `%s`, BTW).

Comment: @Sam @Bob__ okay thanks, that worked. It's strange though- I have been parsing command-line args in the form of strings for a switch statement within the same program, and it didn't require me to call `process_command_line()`. Nevertheless, I will update the question with my solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of users on this question, here is my updated and functioning solution. The problem was that I wasn't calling the second function within my `main` function.

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int process_command_line(int argc, char *argv[]);   //declaration for command-line function

char str2[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    process_command_line(argc, argv); //This was missing in my first attempt
    printf("%s", str2);
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}

//This function reads in the arguments 
int process_command_line(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Missing program arguments.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //first argument is always the executable name (argv[0])

    //second argument reads in the input file name  
    strcpy(str2, argv[1]);

}
```